# Google Chart - BarChart

Tags: google-visualization, bar-chart

I'm using BarChart from Google Chart and I'd like to fix this problem. The text is exceeding your Limit. I don't know how can I fix it, someone knows what could I do?

[image]

It should be:

[image]

It's my javascript code below?

```
google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {

    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Ano');
    data.addColumn({ 'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': { 'html': true } });
    data.addColumn('number', 'Valor Realizado');
    data.addColumn('number', 'idPessoa');

    for (i = 0; i < Object.keys(dataDB).length; i++) {
        var ano = dataDB[i].Ano.toString();
        var valor = (dataDB[i].ValorRealizada);
        var idPessoa = (dataDB[i].IdPessoa);
        data.addRow([ano, createCustomHTMLContent('anual'), valor, idPessoa]);
    }

    var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
    view.setColumns([0, 1, 2,
                     {
                         calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 2,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation"
                     }]);

    var options = {
        width: 1000,
        height: 400,
        focusTarget: 'category',
        tooltip: { isHtml: true },
        hAxis: { textPosition: 'none' },
        legend: { position: 'none' },
        chartArea: { left: 50, top: 30, width: "70%", height: "200%" },
        bar: { groupWidth: "25" }

    };

    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ decimalSymbol: ',', groupingSymbol: '.', negativeColor: 'red', negativeParens: true, prefix: 'R$' });
    formatter.format(data, 2);

    var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("divResultado"));
    chart.draw(view, options);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function () {
        var selection = chart.getSelection();
        if (selection.length) {
            var row = selection[0].row;
            var ano = data.getValue(row, 0);
            var valor = data.getValue(row, 2);
            var idPessoa = data.getValue(row, 3);
            if (valor > 0)
                CallMensal(idPessoa, ano);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

seems to work fine here, see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["corechart"] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Ano');
  data.addColumn({ 'type': 'string', 'role': 'tooltip', 'p': { 'html': true } });
  data.addColumn('number', 'Valor Realizado');

  data.addRow(['2013', '', 120520097.31]);
  data.addRow(['2014', '', 875436546.78]);
  data.addRow(['2015', '', 929521097.31]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1, 2, {
calc: "stringify",
sourceColumn: 2,
type: "string",
role: "annotation"
  }]);

  var options = {
width: 1000,
height: 400,
focusTarget: 'category',
tooltip: { isHtml: true },
hAxis: { textPosition: 'none' },
legend: { position: 'none' },
chartArea: { left: 50, top: 30, width: "70%", height: "200%" },
bar: { groupWidth: "25" }
  };

  var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({ decimalSymbol: ',', groupingSymbol: '.', negativeColor: 'red', negativeParens: true, prefix: 'R$' });
  formatter.format(data, 2);

  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("divResultado"));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="divResultado"></div>
```

Comment: is there more code or something else that could affect the chart, like css?